# Phonegap iOS Front Camera - Flipped Image

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, image-rotation

I am using Phonegap to retrieve a camera picture and then output it on a HTML5 canvas.

Everything works well if I use the back camera, but if I use the front camera, the image shows up upside down.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Is there any way I can find out which camera was used to take the picture?

Following is my code:

```
//take picture on click
$("#camera").click(function(){
    //Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
})

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved in base64 format.
// It draws the photo on the canvas.
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function(){
        drawImage(cbook, this);
    };
    imageObj.src = imageData;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting `correctOrientation` option? It might help.

Comment: Any luck on this? I am stuck on this particular issue